# Style Nested XML-tags differently in InDesign, JavaScript

Tags: xml, scripting, tags, adobe-indesign

To import SMGL in InDesign I

1. changed the first line in `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`
2. decoded entities and now I have the problem of nested Tags which should belong to different Paragraph-Styles

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <ESSAY>
        <TITEL>My Headline1 - somehow similar to h1</TITEL>
        <ABSTRACT>
            <TITEL>My Headline2 - somehow similar to h2</TITEL>
        </ABSTRACT>
    </ESSAY>
<Root>
```

I need to style the title-tag differently in each context.

Of course this is a very short example. In fact the documents are full of those nested Tags.

I know there is XSLT to do the job but how would a scripting-solution in InDesign look like with XMLImportMap?

Which would be more convenient and adaptable?

Here is an idea:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2254770

Answer (score 1):

You can't adress different styles for a same tag at the import stage nor later in the map Styles To tags dialog. You need to either change tags per xslt as suggested, or set styles with XSLT (see namespaced attributes such as aid:cstyle and aid:pstyle) or use a script to apply styles given the specific node context.